# Showing there is a constant for which an inequality holds true

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I'm supposed to show that for $x>0$ and $p>0$ there is a constant $C$ such that $e^x\ge Cx^p$. The constant $C$ depends on $p$ but not on $x$. After analysing the behaviour of the graphs of those functions, below I present my approach to this problem, but it's most likely wrong as it doesn't yield $C$ as a constant.

Without constant:
$$e^x\ge x^p$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} e^x = e^0 = 1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^p = 0^p = 0$$
Therefore $e^x\gt x^p$ as $x\to 0^+$.

For the inequality to hold for $x\gt 0$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x\ge \frac{d}{dx}x^p$$
We may disprove this inequality by contradiction, i.e.:

Let $x=1\land p=3$
$$e^x=e^1=e$$
$$px^{p-1}=3x^{3-1}=3\gt e$$

By adding a constant $C$ we may mitigate this error by adjusting the value of $C$ depending on $p$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(Cx^p)=Cpx^{p-1}$$

Again, as this is probably wrong anyway, could you give me some advice on how else I should tackle this problem? I'm in highschool and so should not be using anything beyond basic differential calculus.

What follows is finding the limit $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^p}$$
by using the obtained result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^p}$. Then $f'(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^{p+1}}(x-p)$, so $f$ is decreasing on $(0,p)$ and increasing on $(p,\infty)$, hence $$\min_{(0,\infty)}f=f(p)=\dfrac{e^p}{p^p}$$ what means that for all $x>0$ we have $$f(x)\ge \dfrac{e^p}{p^p}$$ equivalent $$e^x\ge \dfrac{e^p}{p^p}\cdot x^p$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

$$ e^x \geq C_p\cdot x^p $$
is equivalent to:
$$ e^{x/p} \geq C_p^{1/p} x $$ 
that is a convexity inequality. In order to find the optimal constant, we just need to find a tangent line to the graph of $f_p(x)=e^{x/p}$ that goes through the origin. The equation of the tangent line at $x=x_0$ is given by:
$$ y = \frac{1}{p}e^{x_0/p} (x-x_0) + e^{x_0/p} $$
and it goes through the origin iff $x_0=p$, so the optimal constant is $C_p^{1/p}=\frac{e}{p}$ and

> $$ e^{x} \geq \left(\frac{e}{p}\right)^p\,x^p $$

follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will consider this as well.